# Admob and Awkward Libgdx Display Behavior

Tags: java, android, mobile, libgdx, admob

I looked for some answers in SO but I couldn't find anything. I developed a game with libgdx for android. And I added ads with admob. Everything is good with game but ads not displaying in game. If I press home button of my mobile, send game to back and press again home button and open game again. Ads shown correctly. How can I fix this behavior to show ads from beginning?

MyCode like below

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
AdView adView;
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();



    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);


    View gameView = initializeForView(new NewGame(), config);


    adView = new AdView(this); 
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    layout.addView(gameView);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);


    setContentView(layout);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    adView.resume();
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hiding and showing the adview before setContentView.

```
adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

If this won't work, just ad a listener to your adview and do the same

```
 adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }        
});
```

Comment: First one did not work but second one worked. I understand what we do but I don't understand why we have to do that :)

Comment: Maybe some caches are cleared or something , anyways, glad I helped :)